# Android (Samsung S22) keeps reporting mobile data usage long after eSIM is deleted

Tags: samsung, security, mobile-data, connection-issues, esim

In January 2023 I've used [Airalo's](https://www.airalo.com/) eSIM in UAE for about a week. I've deleted the eSIM upon return. Three months later I've noticed that my phone keeps reporting mobile data usage incurred by that eSIM, although the eSIM itself can't be found anywhere else in the settings and, hence, can't be deleted.

[image]

It has its own section in the "Mobile Data" screen, with its own date range, consistently reporting mobile data usage month to month! <strike>Sometimes it is more than WiFi and my actual SIM combined!</strike> Obviously, I'm not getting billed for this data (otherwise I would have noticed it much earlier), but I did notice that my phone started to have connectivity issue since my return from UAE. It disconnects from the mobile network from time to time, and it takes several minutes to re-connect back.

Did anyone experience similar issue? What could be the reason?

UPD: After setting same billing cycle on all connections, it seems mobile data from eSIM matches that of my regular SIM. So, I guess it's a bug in Samsung software?